# How to get the performance KPI's from performance.window.performance.timing output?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, window-object

Trying to fetch the UI Performance KPI's using puppeteer framework, I have the following script

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const select = require('puppeteer-select');

(async () => {
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        args: ['--start-maximized',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'],
        defaultViewport: null
    };
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const url = "http://app.contries/user_interface";
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    try {
        //Launch URL
        await page.goto(url);
        const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
            await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
        );
        console.log(performanceTiming);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {

        await page.waitFor(10000);
        console.log("Closing the browser session")
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

And the output of the above piece of script is:

```
connectStart: 1600180693460,            
navigationStart: 1600180692020,
loadEventEnd: 1600180700487,                
domLoading: 1600180697154,                  
secureConnectionStart: 0,
fetchStart: 1600180692021, 
domContentLoadedEventStart: 1600180700039, 
responseStart: 1600180697148,               
responseEnd: 1600180697215,                 
domInteractive: 1600180700038,              
domainLookupEnd: 1600180693460,                 
redirectStart: 0,                               
requestStart: 1600180693764,
unloadEventEnd: 0,
unloadEventStart: 0, 
domComplete: 1600180700205,                     
domainLookupStart: 1600180693460,           
loadEventStart: 1600180700205,                  
domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1600180700089,    
redirectEnd: 0,                             
connectEnd: 1600180693764
```

How to get the following KPI's from the above output:

1. Time to title
2. Time to start render
3. Time to interact
4. DNS look up time
5. Connection Time
6. Time to first byte
7. Time to last byte
8. Overall wait